# Which is best - PHP + Mysql query OR Javascript + JSON - to replace wrote numbers by names?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, replace

I'm getting grouped ids numbers with GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL, so I get something like :

```
row 1: 3,4,11,2
row 2: 5,11
row 3: 5,11
```

So if I want to replace that ids to their names, which is the best way?

**PHP + MySQL**

Explode string (3,4,11,2) > Do individual consults in MySQL calling the name of each given id

***OR***

**Jscript + JSON**

Explode string (3,4,11,2) > rewrite to something that I could find with javascript like: `<span class="replaceThis">3</span>
<span class="replaceThis">4</span>
<span class="replaceThis">11</span>
<span class="replaceThis">12</span>`

Create a JSON file (using PHP+Mysql) with all my id and tags like:

```
data: {id: 1, name:'dog'},{id: 2, name:'cat'},{id: 3, name:'dog'}
```

And made javascript find all `<span class="replaceThis">` into the page and for each one replace the innerHTML by name.

Well, PHP + MySql is my first solution, but I don't think it would have a good performance   making a lot of individual queries in MYSQL. I think Javascript + Json would be better but it looks more complex to me. I don't really know how I could do this.

It is just for show on page, it wont be used as variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting grouped ids numbers with GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL [..]

Then just join with the table that has the names and GROUP_CONCAT those names instead of the ids (or do both GROUP_CONCAT if you want). Then just use the result in PHP.

Comment: You are right! But if I needed to use this replace function on other cases and I really needed to build a function for this, which solutions is the best?